# How can Data will show dynamically on the pages

Tags: android

In my database there is a table where every time multiple records will come.I have a screen where I have to show all the data,means first row display in first page second row data will display on second page,so how can I do this.how can I show page dynamically.In my page there is are so many images and I am taking text view on my images and data will show on these text view.

How can I do this please help me..

Comment: multiple records means around how many , 9-10 or more?

Comment: multiple records, and even you want show one record in page, do you really think this idea looks nice?

Comment: its dynamic I dont know how many records!!that is 20 27 don't know depends upon user

Comment: yaa I have to do this like..My screen is there.this screen is full of images and those images having a textviews,I have to show one row data in one page.then I want this page will call again and will show second row data on second page

Comment: means page is only one,but after scrolling the data will be change according to the row..Can I do this please help me

Comment: don't know what you want to implement exactly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6135/discussion-between-user1061793-and-paresh-mayani)

Answer (score 0):

you can use View pager for thatif you have 20 rows then it will create 20 views and you can scrollThat Views one by one

Here is one simple example of VIewPager
http://code.google.com/p/viewpagerexample/